# Returning XY values in Google Distance Matrix

Tags: python, qgis, google-distancematrix-api

I have some simple code set up to produce drive times from one origin to several destinations using the Google Distance Matrix API. This part seems to be working perfectly fine; my issue is that the destinations come back as addresses rather than the XY values that I entered them in as. I'll eventually be moving this data back into QGIS and would like to avoid the extra step of geocoding the distance results. Doesn't look like this is a built-in option with the API—any other suggestions?

Comment: you can keep the (x,y) coordinates in one array, distances obtained in another array, then match them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **GeoCoding Api** on the origin and destination. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051770/2802352) answer.