# how to get coordiantes in response instead of origin & destination addresses in Google Map Distance Matrix API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, distance-matrix

I'm using google distance matrix api in my android application. I'm calling Google distance matrix api by sending origin and destination to API.

API returns response as:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Islamabad, Islamabad Capital Territory, Pakistan" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Lahore, Punjab, Pakistan" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "234 mi",
                  "value" : 376505
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "4 hours 20 mins",
                  "value" : 15608
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I want to get destination & origin coordinates instead of location addresses.

(I need coordinates for some comparison purpose)

Is there an option to get coordinates or can you sugguest some other third party libraries that can get me the desired response.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get **address** , make another api call with **GeoCoding Api**.It will return lat long like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=YOUR_LOCATION&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

[Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)